# Performance of Azure AppFabric Access Control Service during claims transformation

Tags: azure, cloud, access-control, claims-based-identity

Does anybody know any performance test results for rules transformation engine on Azure ACS?
What about the performance during claims transformation?

Can I use it to effectively manage roles for a few million users (with additional 20 transformation rules per user)?  Does it/can it work effectively in such scenario?

For instance if "internal-user-id" input claim contains "some-user@some.IdP" then role output claim should contain "RestrictedUser".

What about cascading transformations?
Are they executed in order they are declared?
It means if some claims transformation rule creates InvoiceMode output claim and other claims transformation rule uses it as input claim then it produces final output claim based on InvoiceMode claim or nothing?

Answer (score 0):

Although i have not tested this,  but it might seem fair you'll hit some performance issues when putting it all on the acs. However, the limits on ACS have been released per the July 2011 update

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg429787.aspx

You could also consider to use the ClaimsAuthorizationManager to do your complex transformations in code. for some in-depth examples you might want to check out the [Identity Training Kit VS2010](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14347)